# Server unable to find view for POSTbut can find it in GET

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js

I have some code that is supposed to validate a user logging into my server, however it doesn't want to post it. My get request has no problem loading the very same "/login" as my post but for some reason it doesn't want to load it during the POST. Sorry if my code is a little inefficient and hard to read, still trying to get the hang of javascript.

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    req.body.userAgent = req.get('User-Agent');
    dataServiceAuth.checkUser(req.body).then((user) => {
        req.session.user = {
            userName: user.username,
            email: user.email,
            loginHistory: user.loginHistory
        }
        res.redirect('/employees');
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.render("login", {errorMessage: err, userName: req.body.userName});
    });
});
```

and the function in the POST

```
module.exports.checkUser = function (userData) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        User.find({ user: userData.userName }).exec().then((user) => {
            if (user == undefined || user.length == 0) {
                reject("Unable to find user: " + userData.userName);
            }
            else if (user[0].password != userData.password) {
                reject("Incorrect Password for user: " + userData.userName);
            }
            else if (user[0].password == userData.password) {
                users[0].loginHistory.push({dateTime: (new Date()).toString(), userAgent: userData.userAgent});
                user[0].update({userName: userData.userName}, {$set: {loginHistory: user[0].loginHistory}}.exec().then((user) => {
                    resolve(user[0]);
                }).catch((err) => {
                    reject("There was an error verifying the user: ${err}");
                }))
            }
        }).catch((err) => {
            reject("Unable to find user: " + userData.user);
        });
    });
};
```

My [Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbyWF.png) looks like this
and my Handlebars file looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <h2>Log In</h2>
        <hr />


        {{#if errorMessage}}
            <div class="alert alertdanger">
                <strong>Error:</strong> {{errorMessage}}</div>
        {{/if}}
        <form method="post" action="/login">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" id="userName" name="userName" type="text" placeholder="User Name" required value=""
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" value="Login" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Express version 4 and above requires extra middle-ware layer to handle POST request. This middle-ware is called as ‘bodyParser’. This used to be internal part of Express framework but here I think you need to install it separately like this `npm install --save body-parser`

Comment: Thank you, I had accidentally forgot to include --save when I last installed it and had switched from my laptop to my desktop to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You should realize that requesting the same route through GET and POST methods does different things.

When you use the GET method, the reason that it has no problem loading the page is because (from what I assume) you would have specified a specific file (probably this login form) to be rendered when a request is received.

In case of the POST request though, you are carrying out operations on the form data sent with the request, and hence there could be a number of reasons you're facing issues with it. Maybe you haven't configured bodyParser to parse nested objects, as Yaswant's answer stated. Or maybe there's some other issue in your code.

It would be helpful if you could give a little more detail on what error you're facing, and if you could post your complete app.js file.

Comment: I forgot to include --save while installing body parser initially, so after I switched computers I had no body parser.